# Can't display a PNG using Glut or OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Code is here:

```
void readOIIOImage( const char* fname, float* img)
{
   int xres, yres;
   ImageInput *in = ImageInput::create (fname);
   if (! in) {return;}
   ImageSpec spec;
   in->open (fname, spec);
   xres = spec.width;
   yres = spec.height;
   iwidth = spec.width;
   iheight = spec.height;

   channels = spec.nchannels;
   cout << "\n";

   pixels = new float[xres*yres*channels];
   in->read_image (TypeDesc::FLOAT, pixels);
   long index = 0;
   for( int j=0;j<yres;j++)
   {
      for( int i=0;i<xres;i++ )
      {
         for( int c=0;c<channels;c++ )
         {
            img[ (i + xres*(yres - j - 1))*channels + c ] = pixels[index++];

         }
      }
   }
   in->close ();
   delete in;
}
```

Currently, my code produces JPG files fine. It has the ability to read the file's information, and display it fine. However, when I try reading in a PNG file, it doesn't display correctly at all. Usually, it kind of displays the same distorted version of the image in three separate columns on the display. It's very strange. Any idea why this is happening with the given code?

Additionally, the JPG files all have 3 channels. The PNG has 2.

fname is simply a filename, and img is `new float[3*size];

Any help would be great. Thanks.`

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, it kind of displays the same distorted version of the image in three separate columns on the display. It's very strange. Any idea why this is happening with the given code?

This reads a lot like the output you get from the decoder is in row-planar format. Planar means, that you get individual rows one for every channel one-after another. The distortion and the discrepancy between number of channels in PNG and apparent count of channels are likely due to alignment mismatch. Now you didn't specify which image decoder library you're using exactly, so I can't look up information in how it communicates the layout of the pixel buffer. I suppose you can read the necessary information from `ImageSpec`.

Anyway, you'll have to rearrange your pixel buffer rearrangement loop indexing a bit so that consecutive row-planes are interleaved into channel-tuples.

Of course you could as well use a ready to use imagefile-to-OpenGL reader library. DevIL is thrown around a lot, but it's not very well maintained. [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) seems to be a popular choice these days.

Comment: Yea I feel it is something along those lines. Trying to follow the logic, but nothing is coming up.